# Angular JS - How do I stop repeating same selected dropdown data from multiple table

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm new in Angular and I'm trying to create a list of table, where each table will be responsible to show data of an object. However, when I try to select something from a dropdown in a table... the same data get selected by another dropdown in another table.

```
<div ng-repeat="appl in applMasterList">
   <h4>{{appl.Name}}</h4>
   <div class="table-responsive">
       <table class="table table-striped table-bordered" style="margin-bottom: 0">
           <tr>           
               <th>
                   Responsible Person
               </th>
           </tr>
           <tr ng-repeat="list in appl.standardApplications">         
               <td>
                   <div class="form-group">
                       <ui-select class="form-control" id="contact" g-required="Required" multiple ng-model="select[$index]" theme="bootstrap" ng-disabled="ctrl.disabled" close-on-select="true" title="Select Responsible Person" >
                           <ui-select-match placeholder="Select Responsible Person..." ng-required="Required">{{$item.DisplayName}}</ui-select-match>
                           <ui-select-choices repeat="contactDetail in contactlist | filter:$select.search">
                               {{contactDetail.DisplayName}}
                           </ui-select-choices>
                       </ui-select>
                   </div>
               </td>              
           </tr>
       </table>
   </div>
   <br />
</div>
```

---

```
app.controller('StdController', function ($scope) {

  $scope.select = [];

});
```

I'm sure I've done something wrong but due to lack of experience in Angular, I'm unable to identify the problem here. Would really appreciate any help. Thank you.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Use the `track by` option

```
ui-select-choices repeat="contactDetail in contactlist track by contactDetail.id | filter:$select.search"
```